# Accessing a common property in a factory function

Tags: javascript

Say I want to have a counter in a factory function that counts the number of objects that were made, I can do it as such:

```js
function foo(){
    // Factory code
    this.counter = this.counter? this.counter + 1 : 1
    console.log(this.counter)
}

let a = foo(); // Logs 1 
let b = foo(); // Logs 2,
console.log(foo.counter) // undefined
```

What this shows, is that the `counter` property is being saved and edited on the `foo` function object. But `foo.counter` is undefined. So my question is:

Where is the property being saved and how can I access it?

Comment: `this` is not the function. In a browser, `this == window`

Comment: In non-strict mode, in a function called "normally", `this` refers to the global object.

Comment: It's `window.counter`. So it's just a global variable named `counter`.

Comment: Try adding `function bar() { console.log(this.counter); }`. You'll see that it shows the same counter.

Comment: Wow! Today I learned. Thank you very much. In a similar vein, am I able to create a counter in factory function similar?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried console.log(counter) and it's '2' :')

Comment: Use `foo.counter` instead of `this.counter` if you want to store a property on the function.

Comment: Related: [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling for the explanation and extra information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a static property to count.

```js
function foo(){
    // Factory code
    foo.counter = foo.counter? foo.counter + 1 : 1;
    console.log(foo.counter)
}

let a = foo();
let b = foo();
console.log(foo.counter)
```

---

In simple words `this` refers to the context of the current object instance, whereas static property refers to the prototype.
Static properties are not directly accessible by this keyword. To access them you need to use its prototype name. Like here in the above code `foo.<your_property_name>`. Even static methods are called in the same way `foo.<your_method_name>()`.

---

You can get the basic difference of both with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` for instance and its prototype(will avoid using an **object** to point factory function to void confusion). The instance has its own property referring to the current object context, whereas the prototype has its own set of properties.

```js
function foo(){
  this.count = 1;
  foo.myOwnCount = 1;
}
const a = new foo();
const b = new foo();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo));
```

You can see instance have access to `count` property which can be accessed with `this` keyword but not to `myOwnCount`. And prototype has access to `myOwnCount` (which can be accessed with the prototype name), but not `count`.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I need. Appreciate it, as well as the comments on the questions explaining what was actually happening with `this`